# Dreamweaver CS3 hogs CPU

Tags: windows, windows-vista, cpu-usage

Whenever Adobe Dreamweaver CS3 is open, it uses 100% of an entire core of my CPU. I have Windows Vista x86.

A few google searches have offered me the advice of excluding Dreamweaver from DEP, although I already have DEP switched on only for core Windows services.

Comment: Have you checked that you have installed any of the latest updates available from Adobe? And this may be lame, but have you tried re-installing/repairing the install?

Comment: Yes, Yes it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been issues (crashes &c) with installations of Dreamweaver when Anti-virus software has been running. [There is an Adobe TechNote](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/154/tn_15481.html) that goes through all this in detail. Worth a look if you've not gone through it already.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I'm not going to point any fingers or pass any judgements here (how do you think I found out about this problem myself), but this is a very very common side-effect of one of the early cracks for the dreamweaver.exe to remove the activation procedure.

There was a 2nd version of the crack, but it screwed up the templating system. So it's six of one, half a dozen of the answer, and I shall sit back and wait for this answer to be deleted or flagged.

Comment: I have CS4 and get similar issues at random (and commonly when editing CSS heavy sites). I have the genuine version - always have and will. I missed CS3 and went from CS2-4 and there are so many bugs like this, but overall, I stick with Adobe as the suite offers the easiest production line!

Comment: ... Although not excluding that he could be using a dodgy copy, just saying that genuine copies are not problem free!